# Oracle concatenate two int columns, make them date and select a date from them

Tags: sql, oracle, date, merge

I have column REF_YEAR and column REF_MONTH. Both are int columns.
I want to select a range of dates between these two ranges.

for example

```
select *
from table
where date between '05/2020' and '12/2021'
```

Can i do something like that but with similar results for int columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you'd

```
select *
from your_table
where to_date(ref_year || lpad(ref_month, 2, '0'), 'yyyymm') 
      between date '2020-05-01' and date '2021-12-01'
```

i.e. you'd have to "convert" (`to_date`) `ref_year` concatenated with `ref_month` (left-padded with zero up to 2 characters in length because May 2021 isn't 20215 but 202105), using appropriate format mask (`yyyymm`) and compare it to valid date values, e.g. date literals I used.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a single proper date column here, rather than separate columns for the month and year.  That being said, integer month and year columns is still workable.  Using your example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REF_YEAR = 2020 AND REF_MONTH >= 5 OR REF_YEAR = 2021;
```

Note that the above logic would include the entire 2021 calendar year, including the entire month of December.  This is what I imagine you want; if you instead want to exclude December, we would have to change the logic slightly.  That being said, it would be much better to maintain a single date column `REF_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REF_DATE >= date '2020-05-01' AND REF_DATE < date '2022-01-01''
```